# Driving distance between 2 points using commercial roads

Tags: driving

How can I get Driving distance between 2 points using only roads available to commercial vehicles?

Comment: This needs some additional details. What software are you using? What road network data do you have?

Comment: Look into manufacturers of truck driver GPS units.  That would be a portable option unless you want to do it in a GIS system, which would mean you'd need to either find a road dataset that specifies vehicle type or somehow create it.